# Rectangle drawn always is erased when the next is created

Tags: delphi, canvas, draw, delphi-10.3-rio

In the code below I would like the previously drawn rectangle to not be erased when the next rectangle is drawn. How achieve this?

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FSelecting: Boolean;
    FSelection: TRect;
    pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4: Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FSelection.Left := X;
  FSelection.Top := Y;
  FSelecting := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if FSelecting then
  begin
    FSelection.Right := X;
    FSelection.Bottom := Y;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FSelecting := false;
  FSelection.Right := X;
  FSelection.Bottom := Y;
  Invalidate;

  FSelection.NormalizeRect;
  if FSelection.IsEmpty then

  else
  begin
    pos1 := FSelection.Left;
    pos2 := FSelection.Top;
    pos3 := X;
    pos4 := Y;

  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Rectangle(FSelection);
end;
```

Comment: Remember each rectangle in a collection, and draw them all when you are asked to paint. The system doesn't remember historical painting. Your job is to draw the entire surface each time you are asked to paint.

Comment: `Paint` always draws from nothing.  If you want to draw multiple rectangles you need to store that information - a `TList<TRect>` would not be a bad option.  Then in `FormPaint` enumerate the list and draw each rectangle.  You would also need to manage removing rectangles from the list when they were no longer needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the form's client area is invalidated the entire surface is marked for redrawing. The next time `OnPaint` is called, what is painted is what is in the event handler. You draw one rectangle and so you see one.

You need to accumulate the information related to the rectangles you need to draw. Then in the paint handler, you can refer to the information and draw them all.

Below example is the slightly modified version of the code in the question. It substitutes a [`TQueue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TQueue) of rectangles in the place of unused integer variables (pos1, pos2..). A rectangle is queued and any excess rectangle is dequeued when mouse the button is released. Maximum number of recalled rectangles is defined by a constant. The paint handler enumerates the queue to draw the rectangles.

```delphi
uses
  ..., generics.collections;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FSelecting: Boolean;
    FSelection: TRect;
    FRectangles: TQueue<TRect>;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  MAXRECTANGLECOUNT = 2;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FRectangles := TQueue<TRect>.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FRectangles.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FSelection.Left := X;
  FSelection.Top := Y;
  FSelecting := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if FSelecting then
  begin
    FSelection.Right := X;
    FSelection.Bottom := Y;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FSelecting := false;
  FSelection.Right := X;
  FSelection.Bottom := Y;
  Invalidate;

  FSelection.NormalizeRect;
  if not FSelection.IsEmpty then
  begin
    FRectangles.Enqueue(FSelection);
    if FRectangles.Count > MAXRECTANGLECOUNT then
      FRectangles.Dequeue;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Rectangle(FSelection);

  for R in FRectangles do
    Canvas.Rectangle(R);
end;

end.
```